# How to add an image in a section of a one-page website

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

I'm building a one-page theme on WordPress.

I have the text on the left hand side and would like to insert a picture on the right however when I tried to add the picture in through code I get this error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'template_directory' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/CVTheme2015/front-page.php on line 21

Is there any forums or video tutorials that could help me ?

```
<div class="indent">
    <section id="meet">
        <?php  
            $query = new WP_Query('pagename=about-us-single');
            //The Loop
            if ($query ->have_posts()){
                while ($query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    echo '<h1 class="section-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';
                    echo '<div class="page">';
                    the_content();
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="sun_and_wind">';
                    echo '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.jpg" />;'
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }
            /* Restore original Post Data */
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </section>
</div>
```

I would like to create something like the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'template_directory' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/CVTheme2015/front-page.php on line 21

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$dir = bloginfo('template_directory');

echo "<img src='$dir/images/logo.jpg' />;"
```

Comment: Hey next2u just tried that. No luck just this was added at the bottom of the section:
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/CVTheme2015;